# presentModalViewController not presenting new view

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

*sigh* The Friday before WWDC isn't a good time to be asking this, but it's worth a try.

I created a UIViewController-based project, and from the first VC I'm trying to load a second, via a button action method. I execute the following code:

```
SaveLocationViewController *saveLocationViewController = [[SaveLocationViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"SaveLocationViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:saveLocationViewController animated:YES];
```

And... nothing visible happens. Via breakpoints I can see that both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear are being called in saveLocationViewController, so it is getting loaded, but the view is not being displayed.

saveLocationViewController contains a call to initWithNibName, part of Apple's boilerplate code, but taking it out doesn't make any difference.  The NIB appears to be correct, the view is hooked up, and I'm not getting any errors, the view just doesn't display.  I still see the original view.

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: May be you can try out cleaning the source. Remove build folder from the source and delete the application from the simulator and than again try. This happened sometime to me also and this did the trick.

Comment: Do a Build/Clean All Targets first, just to be thorough.

Comment: PengOne and Jennis were correct - a full clean fixed the problem.  Xcode 4 strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

1. i saw your code and you have given your object name same as your class name with just change in the first character that's s so try to avoid such type of naming conventions, give object names like saveLocationObject or something like that.
2. Also i would like you to see whether the action method is assigned to the buttons touch up inside method or not may be you have forgot to assign it because as far as your code is concerned its ok doesn't have any problem.
3. Now if the problem still persists then in that case clean the build and then give it a try.

Do let me know if the issue still remains or is solved.